# photoswipe script for mobile issue

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, mobile

I am using photoswipe script it's working fine on all the phone.

I have a small issue when image loads it takes time to load the image at that time I want loader image to show.

```
<link href="css/photoswipe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/klass.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    (function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){

        $(document).ready(function(){

            var options = {};
            $("#Gallery a").photoSwipe(options);

        });


    }(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

</script>   
</head>

<ul id="Gallery" class="gallery">

    <li><a href="images/full/001.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/001.jpg" alt="Image 001" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/002.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/002.jpg" alt="Image 002" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/003.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/003.jpg" alt="Image 003" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/004.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/004.jpg" alt="Image 004" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/005.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/005.jpg" alt="Image 005" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/006.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/006.jpg" alt="Image 006" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/007.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/007.jpg" alt="Image 007" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/008.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/008.jpg" alt="Image 008" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/009.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/009.jpg" alt="Image 009" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/010.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/010.jpg" alt="Image 010" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/011.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/011.jpg" alt="Image 011" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/012.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/012.jpg" alt="Image 012" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/013.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/013.jpg" alt="Image 013" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/014.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/014.jpg" alt="Image 014" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/015.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/015.jpg" alt="Image 015" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/016.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/016.jpg" alt="Image 016" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/017.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/017.jpg" alt="Image 017" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/018.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/018.jpg" alt="Image 018" /></a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Photoswipe automatically displays a circular image loading gif when downloading an image.  If this is not showing you may need to check your CSS image paths to ensure they are correct.

Comment: yes i checked it
The path was correct. I just give the background image Full URL Path
It works now
Thank you for your help :-)